# VBA Keydown Problems

Tags: excel, vba, putty, keydown

I'm trying to create a VBA script that will open up a Putty window, enter in user information (username, password, etc), key down (down arrow) to the correct menu option, and then open that menu option.

The script works fine except I can't get the keydown function to work correctly with putty. Is the script loosing focus on the window? Am I incorrectly using the keydown function? Is there are better way to write this action?

```
  Sub Putty()
    '
   Dim puttyID As String

   puttyID = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe", vbNormalFocus)

   newHour = Hour(Now())
   newMinute = Minute(Now())
   newSecond = Second(Now()) + 3
   waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
   Application.Wait waitTime

   SendKeys "information", True
   SendKeys "{ENTER}, True"

  newHour = Hour(Now())
  newMinute = Minute(Now())
  newSecond = Second(Now()) + 3
  waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
  Application.Wait waitTime

  SendKeys "user", True
  SendKeys "~", True

  newHour = Hour(Now())
  newMinute = Minute(Now())
  newSecond = Second(Now()) + 1
  waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
  Application.Wait waitTime

  SendKeys "password", True
  SendKeys "~", True

  newHour = Hour(Now())
  newMinute = Minute(Now())
  newSecond = Second(Now()) + 2
  waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
  Application.Wait waitTime

  SendKeys "ID", True
  SendKeys "~", True
  SendKeys "~", True

  newHour = Hour(Now())
  newMinute = Minute(Now())
  newSecond = Second(Now()) + 2
  waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
  Application.Wait waitTime

  SendKeys "2", True

  newHour = Hour(Now())
  newMinute = Minute(Now())
  newSecond = Second(Now()) + 1
  waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
  Application.Wait waitTime

  SendKeys "{Down}", True
  SendKeys "{Down}", True
  SendKeys "~", True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

The app might not be getting enough time to respond to the SendKeys.  I suggest putting a:

**DoEvents**

statement immediately following any SendKeys statement that seems to be getting ignored.